# How can I make a website such that when a user enters any URL related to the website, it opens up the index page

Tags: html, redirect, web, indexing

Let us suppose I have a static HTML website 'example.com/index.html'  and I have another page that has URL 'example.com/contact-us.html'.

Someone enters the URL 'example.com/contact-us.html' in the browser when he wants to go to contact-us.html page directly. But I want the index page opened in this case. But once the website is loaded on the browser with the index page, the user must be able to navigate through links on the website as per his wish.

Is this possible ? If yes, how ?

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're asking.  Do you mean you never want the user to be able to go directly to a page without using your navigation links or you just want them to not be able to go anywhere until they've seen the home page first?

Comment: user2534880's answer will work, but it's not wholly reliable.  You can mix in cookies or IP tracking in a session but I don't think there is a wholly reliable solution.  May I ask _why_ you're trying to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to prevent users to open pages directly except for the index, you can check the referer, and redirect to the index page if the referer doesn't match your website.

Are you using Apache? If you are, you can use mod_rewrite to do this.

First, enable mod_rewrite, usually by uncommenting the following line in the `httpd.conf` file:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Then create a `.htaccess` file in the same folder as `index.html` with the following content:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^index.html$ index.html [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://example\.com/.*$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.html [R,L]
```

Comment: +1 This is the "standard" way of doing it (e.g. when someone wants to prevent image hot-linking).  The standard caveat is it's not mandatory for browsers to send Referer, and some people disable it for privacy reasons.